# primes of the form $a^2+b^2=x^2-xy+y^2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b,x,y$ be strict positive integers.
Im intrested in primes $p$ such that $p=a^2+b^2=x^2-xy+y^2$.
What is the analogue PNT for these type of primes ? I think these primes are all the primes  $p \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$.

Comment: so it's just prime number theorem for the arithmetic progression 1 mod 12? no need to consider the form once you know the congruence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), $p$ can be written as $a^2+b^2$ iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $p = 2$. By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280551/26204), $p$ can be written as $x^2-xy+y^2$ iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $p = 3$. A prime $p$ satisfies both if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12}$, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Also note that by the Prime Number Theorem for arithmetic progressions, the number of these primes less than $x$ is asymptotically $\frac{Li(x)}{\varphi(12)}=\frac{Li(x)}{4}$.

Comment: To expand @Tib's comment, there are four residue classes mod 12 which are coprime to 12 (1,5,7,11) and the primes are (ultimately, on average) equally divided between them.