# proof, that if prime natural number $(p) \, \text{ mod } \, 3 = 1$, then it can be presented as $a^2-ab+b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers

Tags: number-theory

This problem is from Eisenstein primes, I already proved, that if $p$ is natural prime, then it can be decomposed into $a^2-ab+b^2$ or it is Eisenstein prime. So we have to prove, that if $p \, \text{ mod } \, 3 =1$ then $p$ is not Eisenstein prime.
Also, I found out, that $p$ is Eisenstein prime if and only if the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ has no solutions $\text{ mod } \,  p$.
So, $x^2+x+1=0$ the same as $(2x+1)^2=-3$. Please, suggest any hints to solve this.

Comment: do you knowwhat the Legendre symbol is?

Comment: only heard about it, i’ll try to use it, thanks

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513263/p-a2-ab-b2-a-b-in-mathbbz?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the theory of quadratic forms. Since $p\equiv1\pmod3$ is equivalent (by quadratic reciprocity) to $-3$ being a square modulo $p$, then $p$ is represented by a positive definite integer quadratic
form of discriminant $-3$. But every such form is equivalent to the form
$x^2-xy+y^2$, by, for instance, the theory of reduced forms. So
the prime $p\equiv1\pmod3$ entails $p$ being represented by $x^2-xy+y^2$.