# $a^2+ab+b^2=1$, how many ordered integer solutions exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the answers to be a=-1, b=0; a=1,b=0; a=0,b=1 and a=0,b=-1. Only 4 pairs, however the answer is 6. Please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay the question is  not exactly a duplicate here the RHS is 1 whereas in  the prev one it is 0

Comment: Try the pair $(1,-1)$.

Comment: The [original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/784821/18398) has now been changed: the right-hand side that was originally 0 has now been edited to 1.

Comment: @amWhy I've deleted my previous comment. This is the same question now as the other one (which was edited). But the wording for closing as a duplicate suggests that the duplicate question has to have an answer. And I was just noting that it didn't. I don't wholly like the wording for duplicates, and I think that repostings of essentially the same question are to be strongly discouraged.

Comment: If it happens again u should let the original question as it is and post another question especially when answers are already there

Comment: @Mark I learned over time that if a post is an exact duplicate of a previous question with both asked by the same OP account, then the requirement that the former question have an upvoted answer is dropped. The system accepts the URL for the (non-answered) duplicated post in this scenarios (i.e. it somehow "knows" that in this situation, the questions were posted by the same user.)

Answer (score 2):

Use quadratic formula for $a$ and you will obtain : $4-3b^2\geq 0\implies b={-1,0,1}$. For each $b$ there exist $2$ a.

Comment: How did you get to 4-3b^2>=0? Please elaborate.

Comment: Check sign of discriminant

Comment: $\left(a+\frac b2\right)^2+\frac 34b^2=1$. Now $\left(a+\frac b2\right)^2\ge0$ hence $\frac 34b^2\le1\iff4-3b^2\ge0$
or even more simply just to do as Awesome suggested.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much.