# Eisenstein integers with norm value of 5

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, eisenstein-integers

I am trying to find out the Eisenstein integers that have norm values of 3,5,7....
I want to see if there is some pattern.

For the norm value of 3, I was able to find six Eisenstein integers.
For the norm value of 7, I was able to find twelve Eisenstein integers.

I am unable to find even a single Eisenstein integer with a norm value of 5.
Is this correct? Do Eisenstein integers with a norm value of 5 not exist or am I missing something? Does it have to do anything with the fact that 5 is a prime Eisenstein integer?

Comment: If we had $5=(a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2)$, then $5$ wouldn’t be a prime Eisenstein integer

Comment: $N(a+b\omega)=a^2-ab+b^2\not\equiv2\pmod3$

Comment: $(2a-b)^2+3b^2=20$ has no integer solution. Brute force shows it very quickly.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479304/p-equiv-2-pmod-3-is-an-odd-prime-prove-that-there-are-no-integers-x-y-sa)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you! it makes sense now

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, i was not able to find any by brute force either!

Comment: And it is the easiest way: $20$, $20-3$, $20-3\cdot2^2$ are not squares, that's all.

Comment: @AnneBauval, yes, I see that. I tried it with $(a-b)^2+ab=5$ and then took the possible cases. $(a-b)^2 \neq 5, 3, 2$ so those three cases get rejected. And in the case of $(a-b)^2=1, 4$. I could not find any a and b which satisfy that and $ab=4,1$ consecutively.

Comment: My search is faster.

Comment: yes, it is @AnneBauval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything.  There are no Eisenstein integers

$(a+b\omega$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $\omega$ a primitive cube root of $1)$ with a norm of $5.$

One way to see this is to note that $N(a+b\omega)=(a+b\omega)(a+b\overline\omega)$ $=a^2-ab+b^2$

$\equiv a^2+2ab+b^2$ $=(a+b)^2\not\equiv2\pmod3,$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479304/p-equiv-2-pmod-3-is-an-odd-prime-prove-that-there-are-no-integers-x-y-sa).

Another way to see this, as suggested in comments by [Anne Bauval](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/386889/anne-bauval), is to note that

$N(a+b\omega)=a^2-ab+b^2=\left(a-\frac12b\right)^2+\frac34b^2=5\iff(2a-b)^2+3b^2=20,$

which has no solutions in integers, because $20, 20-3\cdot1^2,$ and $20-3\cdot2^2$ are not squares

and $20-3\cdot b^2<0$ for integers $b>2$.

Finally, if we had $N(a+b\omega)=(a+b\omega)(a+b\overline\omega)=5$,

then $5$ would not be a prime Eisenstein integer.

Comment: If $a+b\omega$ were a unit, then we'd have $N(a+b\omega)=1$